# Pointers changing values

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Treenode pointers changing values with globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833269/c-treenode-pointers-changing-values-with-globals)

I have a program that is creating a node tree full of various bits (it's actually a recursive descent parser). Anyway, when I get to the end, I assign a pointer to the first "token" that my program is at currently. I assign the 'child' of that node to equal a new node that contains the data that is a token.

So, then my program moves on. That is, it changes the global "token" to be the next value.

The issue I'm then having is that the treenode which was pointing to the appropriate data, now changes too.

That is, let's say that the program is tokenizing a simple string like this.

```
firstvar = 1
```

So, initially the tree says `program->assignStmt->{identifier; firstvar}`

But then, the program moves on to the next token, so now the current global token is `{assignment; =}`, and instead of the assignStmt treenode continuing to have the value `{identifier; firstvar}` it now has the value `{assignment; =}`. The pointer didn't retain the value!

Hopefully this is something you guys can point me to in logic.

EDIT (2:30 pm) :: OKAY... here's some code

```
typedef struct node {
    TOKEN *data;

    struct node *child1, *child2, *child3, *child4, *parent;

} node;

TOKEN *token;
Symbol sym;
struct node *root;

void getsym() 
{
    token = getNextToken();
    sym = token->sym;
}

int main()
{
    getsym();
    //So, right now, from getsym() the global token has the value {identifier; firstvar} 

    struct node* tempNode;
    tempNode = (struct node*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    tempNode->child1 = tempNode->child2 = tempNode->child3 = tempNode->child4 =  NULL;
    tempNode->data = token;

    getsym();
    //BUT NOW from getsym() the global token has the value {assignment; =}, and 
    //subsequently the tempNode->data has changed from what it should be 
    //{identifier; firstvar} to what the global token's new value is: {assignment; =}

}
```