# C Treenode pointers changing values with globals

Tags: c

So, here's the story. I'm trying to create a recursive descent parser that tokenizes a string and then creates a tree of nodes out of those tokens.

All of the pointers for my major classes are working... if you're worked with an RDP before then you know what I'm talking about with program -> statement -> assignStmt... etc. The idea being that the program node has a child that points to the statement node, etc.

Here's the problem. When I get to the end of the treenode I'm pointing to the actual tokens that the tokenizer created from the string.

So, let's say the string is:

```
 firstvar = 1;
```

In this case there are 4 tokens [{id} firstvar], [{assignment} =], [{number} 1], [{scolon}]

And I want my assignStmt node to point to the non-decorator portions of that statement.. namely, child1 of assignStmt would be [{id} firstvar] and child2 would be [{number} 1]...

HOWEVER. When I assign child1 to [{id} firstvar], and then move onward to the next tokens, the value of child1 changes as I move forward. So, if I change my global token to the next token ( in this case [{assignment} =] ) then child1 of the assignStmt changes with it.

Why is this? What can I do?! Thank you!

```
TOKEN* getNextToken(void); 
//only shown here to you know the return... it's working properly elsewhere

typedef struct node {
    TOKEN *data;

    struct node *child1, *child2, *child3, *child4, *parent;

} node;

TOKEN *token;
Symbol sym;
struct node *root;

void getsym() 
{
    token = getNextToken();
    sym = token->sym;
}

int main()
{
    getsym();
    //So, right now, from getsym() the global token has the value {identifier; firstvar} 

    struct node* tempNode;
    tempNode = (struct node*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    tempNode->child1 = tempNode->child2 = tempNode->child3 = tempNode->child4 =  NULL;
    tempNode->data = token;

    getsym();
    //BUT NOW from getsym() the global token has the value {assignment; =}, and 
    //subsequently the tempNode->data has changed from what it should be 
    //{identifier; firstvar} to what the global token's new value is: {assignment; =}

}
```

Comment: have u tried using a debugger

Comment: You should implement the parser so that it has its own logic inside - don't try to map the source code 1:1 to the AST.

Comment: @H2CO3 Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: it seems that you're actually trying to build an abstract semantic graph (ASG) instead of an AST (I assume you want to make evaluation by tree traversal easy, which is a valid reason). So your parser needs to understand the grammar in the sense that it needs to be able to differentiate between semantically significant and insignificant tokens and proceed according to that knowledge.

Comment: @H2CO3 No no, that's not the issue. I'm hiding all of that elsewhere.... my problem is with the pointers. The pointers are giving me a headache.

Comment: oh I see! The thing is that it's quite a lot of code that you posted and I can't see an error at first glance. Try getting rid of the globals in first place.

Comment: How does `getNextToken` look? Does it return a pointer to a static variable or another global variable?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg getNextToken() is actually in an entirely different function. All this code is in one called parser.c and that's from scanner.c .... That said, it is returning a global variable from there

Comment: What kind of data type is TOKEN?  Is this something you defined yourself and could it mask another pointer?

Comment: @Michael Not sure how a code block will work here... but it's a struct, as follows  `typedef struct token {
    Symbol sym;
    char *name;
    char *value;

} TOKEN;`

Comment: Hmm, seems like you should start debugging.  As much as most people will probably say it's a bad idea, I would add a couple of `printf("%p %p", token, tempNode->data);` before and after you call `getsym` to figure out what's changing...

Comment: You say that `getNextToken` returns a pointer to a global variable? but do you change the contents of that variable in each call but still return the same pointer? In that case pointer will be the same and point to the exact same object.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, all over doing that.. it's how I figured out the problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ha! That's exactly the issue... if you want solving credit points, go ahead and just provide an answer. I was pointing to a global variable in the other file! Crazy, didn't know that issue with compilers (I'm using gcc, in case that matters)... it continued to consider it global, it needed to be nested within the `getNextToken()` specifically.

Comment: Sounds like it's something in `getNextToken`. Can you give us a better idea of what's going on in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a global variable, and that pointer will always be the same even if you modify the global variable.

The solution is to either allocate a new object each time, or to not use pointers at all and return the structure directly and let the compiler handle copying of the structures internal values.

Answer (score 2):

Since i can't comment on this due to my low reputation i will add this answer and if have understood your problem you are probably passing a pointer to a function, and the problem is that you probably need a pointer to pointer instead of just a pointer.

in C when you pass values to a function you are passing them by value, not by reference, meaning that the function makes a local copy of that argument and it will work only with that local copy, the problem is that all the changes will affect only the local copy and when the function terminates all the changes will be lost if you will not handle this correctly.

Comment: Hmm... So, I'm confused. With the code is that what it looks like it happening? How would I change it?